# js infinite loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Попал в бесконечный луп с таким фильтром во `vuejs`:

```
sortType(modifications) {
  let avg_discounted_price = Object.values(modifications).reduce((total, {
    discount_price
  }) => total + parseFloat(discount_price), 0)
  let avg_sold = Object.values(modifications).reduce((total, {
    sold
  }) => total + parseInt(sold), 0)
  modifications.sort((a, b) => {
    let weight_a = (avg_discounted_price / parseFloat(a.discount_price)) * (parseInt(a.sold) / avg_sold)
    let weight_b = (avg_discounted_price / parseFloat(b.discount_price)) * (parseInt(b.sold) / avg_sold)
    return weight_a - weight_b
  })
},
```

В чем может быть проблема? почему код запускает сам себя постоянно? Если убрать `sort` - проблемы нет

Comment: попробуй сделать [mcve], чтобы можно было запустить и увидеть бесконечный цикл, по текущему куску кода сложно сказать

Comment: @Grundy я нашел проблему))) modifications который поступает туда при использовании sort на него меняется сразу - что запускает новую сортировку)) и так по кругу)) я сделал копию объекта и с ней сортирую - все ок)) я дебил)